# block matrix version Fox’s matrix multiplication in MPI (using C)

Tags: c, matrix, mpi, block, multiplication

I am stuck with this program for a long time now, so basically i have to multiply 2 n x n matrices on a p x p cartesian grid, p<= n( n divisible by p)

In your program, process 0 of the 2D grid should read the matrices A and B
from a file. Example :

< matrix dimension n>

< Matrix A >

< Matrix B >

---

4

-11.0   -12.0     6.0     9.0
-11.0    12.0     2.0     4.0
8.0     6.0    12.0    11.0
6.0     4.0   -10.0     1.0
2.0    11.0     1.0     7.0
3.0     1.0    -2.0     4.0
1.0     9.0    11.0     3.0
6.0     1.0    -1.0     5.0

I am able to read the matrices into the two arrays A and B using process 0 but i needed some help on the rest of the program.

```
    #include <mpi.h> 
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h> 

    int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
    { 
    int p, rank, k, n;
     float *A = NULL, *B=NULL;
     char filename[FILENAME_MAX];
     //MPI_Status status;
     FILE *file;
     MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
     MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p );
     MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );

     // asks for filename
     if ( rank == 0 ) { 
     printf("p=%d", p);
     printf("Enter filename: ");
     scanf("%s", filename);

     // file is opened
     file = fopen(filename, "r");
     fscanf( file, "%d", &n );
     printf( "\nMatrix size = %d\n", n ); 
     // As per the expected format of the file the size of the matrix comes first in the file
     } 
     // broadcasts the value of n to all the processes
     MPI_Bcast( &n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

     if ( n*n > p ) 
     {
     // since p perfectly divides the n x n matrixes assumed
     if ( rank == 0 ) 
     { 
     printf( "No. of processes must be at least %d\n", n*n );
     fclose( file );
     } 
     MPI_Finalize( );
     exit( 1 );
     }

     //  Read and print input data matrix A and B 
     if ( rank == 0 ) 
     {

     A = (float *) malloc( n*n*sizeof(float) );
     printf( "\nMatrix A:\n" );
     for ( k=0;k<n*n; k++ ) 
     { 
     fscanf( file, "%f", &A[k] );
     printf( "%7.1f", A[k] );
     if ( (k+1)%n == 0 ) printf( "\n" );
     }
     // reads matrix B
     B = (float *) malloc( n*n*sizeof(float) ); 
     printf( "\nMatrix B:\n" );
     for ( k=0;k<n*n; k++ ) 
     { 
     fscanf( file, "%f", &B[k] );
     printf( "%7.1f", B[k] );
     if ( (k+1)%n == 0 ) printf( "\n" );
     } fclose( file );

     }

     MPI_Finalize( ); return 0; 
     }
```

Comment: Please format your post and indent your code.

Comment: oh, actually i just joined this site, i will do it and repost,,here

Comment: could you please help me get started also ?